# No addresses being found with Google geocoding service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Any address I send to the Google geocoding service is returning ZERO_RESULTS.  I am encoding a few hundred addresses, and I haven't hit my limit (would get a different error).  Also, the delay between each request is 2 seconds (or more when I stop execution with the debugger).  No matter what address I try, I get ZERO_RESULTS.  In the past (as soon as a week ago) this has worked fine.  Any ideas?

For example, here is a URI that returns ZERO_RESULTS...

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=801+BALTIMORE+STREET%2c+Hanover%2c+PA%2c+17331&sensor=false

Comment: Strangely, you can search for this location in Google Maps, but if you try to use the [direct link](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=801+Baltimore+Street,+Hanover,+PA+17331&hl=en&sll=40.365277,-82.669252&sspn=6.000921,14.501953&oq=801%2BBALTIMORE%2BSTREET,%2BHanover,%2BPA,%2B17331&t=h&hq=801+Baltimore+Street,+Hanover,+PA+17331&radius=15000&z=13), it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [result on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=801+BALTIMORE+STREET,+Hanover,+PA,+17331&hl=en&sll=45.408106,8.218702&sspn=1.496319,2.438965&hq=801+BALTIMORE+STREET,+Hanover,+PA,+17331&radius=15000&t=m&z=13) is not for an "address", it is for a "place".

There are three entries in the Places database for ["Giant, 801 Baltimore Street, Hanover, PA"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Giant,%20801%20BALTIMORE%20STREET,%20Hanover,%20PA,%2017331&place=1), but no results from the geocoder for "801 Baltimore Street, Hanover, PA, 17331".

Comment: The [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) only returns results for addresses.  For places you need to use the [Places Library/API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Answer (score 1):

I tried that URL and I discovered there is a 800 and 802 but no 801 baltimore street in hanover PA. Google Maps knows that address and shows a mall or something.

Comment: Thanks.  I would think the geocode service would give an approx address still?  It maps fine in maps.google.com.

Comment: There is no approximated result on that API.

Comment: I just checked the v3 docs.  There is a geometry.location_type that is returned with one of the following four values... ROOFTOP, RANGE_INTERPOLATED, GEOMETRIC_CENTER, APPROXIMATE.  I would expect at least APPROXIMATE to be returned?